# How can I defer the initialization of my level's entities until I need them?

Tags: c++, architecture, design-patterns

I intend to use a level-entity-components hierarchy in my C++ game engine where a "level" is just a container for entities. However, since I'd like to setup all the levels at once (and thus all entities and components) I've stumbled upon a memory management dilemma: since only one level can be run at a time I need somehow to delay an initialization of other level's entities. How can I accomplish that?

I've considered a solution where all the levels derive from some `Level` base class and are initialized in the constructor when needed, but that would require creating a class with just the constructor in it for each level.

Comment: *Why* would you "set up all levels at once"? Why can't you initialize a level when it is actually run?

Comment: Hard-coding assests into *engine* is a terrible idea, even more so if using inheritance to do that.

Answer (score 1):

> I need somehow to delay an initialization of other level's entities

Why not add an `init()` and a `terminate()` methods to your Level class that does just that? `init()` populates your level when you're ready to play it, and `terminate()` cleans everything up when you're done with it.

You might want to consider changing your architecture to have `Level` created only when you need it: with that, you put the initialization code in the constructor, and the termination in the destructor. This would be more in line with RAII's principles.

Comment: The first paragraph made me cringe, the second one relieved me.